# Why doesn't my component unmount even though I implemented componentWillUnmount?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a class component that doesn't unmount, even though I implemented `componentWillUnmount` on it. I tried to `console.log` the mounting phases; it works with the `constructor` and `componentDidUnmount` but not `componentWillUnmount`. Also it gives me an error: `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component` whenever I open this screen. I'm still a new learner and I don't understand the mounting concept  too well.

Here's my code (it doesn't `console.log` "unmount"):

```
  constructor(props) {
    console.log('before');
    super(props);
    this.state = { doctors: '' };
    this.fetchDo = this.fetchDo.bind(this);
  }
  fetchDo() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Doctors')
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let doctorsdata = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });

        this.setState({
          doctors: doctorsdata,
        });
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchDo();
    console.log('mount');
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.fetchDo();
    console.log('unmount');
  }
```

Comment: Okay, so, I think there's a little misunderstanding, or misconception. `componentWillUnmount()` is not something that unmounts your component. It's one of the lifecycle methods that fires upon the component being removed from the DOM. So if the code block doesn't execute when you expect it to, it means that the component hasn't been removed from the DOM.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood it, thanks. So in my case the component didn't unmount, any idea why?

Comment: From what is included in the question thus far, it is unclear as to why the component is not unmounting. Try and see if you can incorporate more parts of your application, and briefly explain the flow. You might be thinking about the overall logic the wrong way. What are you trying to achieve as a whole? And how are you doing it?

Comment: Someone mentioned that it may be a problem caused by my navigation, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe because your component is at the root of your navigation stack.
It is never unmounted if it stays at the bottom of your stack. Try resetting the stack and you will see the console log.

Here is how you can reset your stack.

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'MainActivity' })],
        });
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```